# Dynamic function arguments with Generics

Tags: typescript

Fairly new to typescript.
I encountered this type, in which if you pass "LOGIN" as first parameter, should also ask you for payload.

```
type EVENTS =
  | {
      type: "LOGIN";
      payload: {
        userId: number;
      };
    }
  | { type: "SIGNOUT" };

let myfunc = <Type extends EVENTS["type"]>(
  ...param: Extract<EVENTS, { type: Type }> extends { payload: infer TPayload }
    ? [Type, TPayload]
    : [Type]
) => {};
```

Usage: `myfunc("SIGNOUT")`

**My question**: From where does it infer the `Type` when the function is called (assuming you don't manually specify it using `<>`)?

**My explanation**: TS couldn't evaluate left hand side of `?` yet, but it noticed that in any case, the parameters of function are either `[Type, Payload]` or `[Type]`, in which case the first argument is always `Type`. Hence when user calls the function, interpret first argument as `Type`. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: @jcalz do you suggest my explanation was wrong?

Comment: @jcalz Ok thanks I hope I also explained more or less clearly how I see it. Feel free to comment when done

Comment: So, looking at [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wOAXrm), it appears that the compiler is inferring the first argument as `Type` because it appears in the first position of *either* `[Type]` or `[Type, TPayload]`.  It doesn't have to be both, and it doesn't have to be correct (`myFuncY` in my link shows that it infers from the conditional branch that doesn't end up get taken).  So I'd say the part of your explanation saying "in which case the first argument is always `Type`" is not happening, and it's more like "in which case the first argument is a *candidate* for `Type`".

Comment: Not sure if that's clear... I'm saying that the compiler does not figure out that the first argument is always `Type`, otherwise the `myFuncY` in my example would not behave the way it does.  TS uses heuristics to infer from types, so that given a value `v` of type `XXX extends F<T> ? [T, ...ZZZ] : WWW` or of  `XXX extends F<T> ? WWW : [T, ...ZZZ]`, it considers the type of `v[0]` to be a candidate for `T`, even if it turns out that the conditional type evaluates to `WWW` in that case.  It then *checks* the candidate, and if it works, hooray, otherwise you get an error.

Comment: @jcalz trying to follow but sometimes hard(beginner in TS). So you mean in your second example it actually couldn't even infer T right?

Comment: @jcalz hm yes but one thing to note that is in all your examples the left hand side of ? is evaluatable: `0 extends T`. In my case I think you can't evaluate left hand side of ? unless you know `Type`, isn't it?

Comment: You picked a pretty crazy thing to ask about for a beginner because the inference path is weird (I would absolutely not write `myfunc` the way you have it, because it's not obvious where the compiler will infer the generic type from).   I don't know if it didn't infer `T` "right" because it's not obvious what the right `T` should be, but you can see that it used the `T` in `[T, 1]` as an inference site to produce `"a"` and `"b"` as candidates for `T`, but then those candidates don't work since the first argument has to be `"x"`.

Comment: `0 extends T` is not evaluatable if `T` is an unresolved generic (and neither is `T extends 0` or `[T] extends [0]` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mL2AAw)).  The compiler generally defers evaluation whenever an unresolved generic is being checked, even if higher order analysis would reveal that it has to be one way or the other.  But if that matters to you I could write [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKObZW) where there's no way to know in advance

Comment: @jcalz Sorry what do you mean in last sentence (not from the latest comment but one before it)? You mean this, when I hovered on second function it wrote: `let myfuncY: <"b">(param_0: "x", param_1: 2) => void` So it correctly guessed "b", but still errored. That's what you mean?

Comment: It's not "correct", because `param_0` is supposed to be `"x"`.  In what sense is it correct?  Anyway, at this point, this is just a chat so I might need to disengage. I don't feel confident in writing up an answer yet, because the particular inference path being used in this code is not well documented (or documented at all maybe).

Comment: @jcalz Yeah I also feel I can't follow your latest comments. Anyway here is where I got it from if you are interested: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YE_3WwX-Dl8